# Firefox freezes when using Flash

Tags: firefox, flash, nvidia-graphics-card

I just updated my display driver (Nvidia GTX 560 Ti) to the latest version (331.65) and whenever I try to open a website containing flash-material (Flash version 11.9), Firefox (version 25.0) freezes and throws me the "Stop Plugin"-Dialog.

Meanwhile the TaskManager tells me that 2 Flash processes are open, until I stop the plugin.

I tried disabling the hardware acceleration in Firefox, but it didn't help.
I am using Windows 8 (64).

**What should I do, to fix this?**

Comment: Have you tried to disable all plugins except Flash?

Comment: Yes. No success

Comment: Are you using 32-bit or 64-bit flash player?

Comment: A 32-Bit flash player

Comment: I would try uninstalling it using Add/Remove Programs and download the 64-bit specifically from the website. Don't let FF do this for you automatically

Comment: If 64-bit doesn't work then maybe you should install an older version until Adobe releases a new version. http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html

Comment: I had a typo. I meant that I have a 32-Bit player. At least thats what the Control Panel > System & Security says

Comment: No sweat I updated my comments accordingly so people wont get too confused. I still recommend trying an archived version though.

Comment: *Edit* After initial satisfaction I have to say that it still doesn't work.

Comment: Initial satisfaction? lol sounds like a Las Vegas-Lady of the Night review on Yelp. Anyways you can also try reverting back to the previous nVidia driver but make sure to do a full uninstall and clean out leftover files and do a fresh install of the driver you do want. Updating drivers vs. doing a fresh install has been known to eff things up before.

Comment: Now that I uninstalled all Nvidia drivers (and installed none new), Flash works. But I can still open the Nvidia control panel with right-click on the desktop ???

Comment: @IMX clarify your question.  You make a statement but use ? Which indicates a question...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after updating my GTX 560 Ti driver.  Try restarting your computer.  I spent about two days trying to resolve this without a restart and after I performed the restart, everything worked fine again.

Comment: Just tried it. Unfortunately, itd id not help.

Answer (score 0):

Same Card, same Driver, same Problem! With Firefox 25 it's going even more worse, you don't need flash to produce an error. This happens e.g. during writing here. If I have luck, only the gfx driver crashes and is restarted. With less luck also Firefox crashes. Without any luck: BSOD! Since downgrade to my previous driver (314.22) everything is fine and reminds: never touch a running system without any special reason!